# SetWindowsHooks to Hook another programs

Tags: c#

I'm newbie in WindowHooks,and my target is "Hooks mouse, keyboard, and find information from another process", then I think I will try to hook it. I'm make a Window Application by C# (I don't use DLL).

```
if(hHook == 0)
{
MouseHookProcedure = new HookProc(mainForm.MouseHookProc);
hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,MouseHookProcedure,(IntPtr)0,GetCurrentThreadID())
if(hHook == 0)
MessageBox.Show("SetWindowsHookEx Failed");
return;
```

with

```
MH_MOUSE = 7;
```

and MouseHookProc is a public static int in windows application (I wrote it inside windows application).
The hook works, but only on itself, but I need it hooks on another process. I tried to change from`GetCurrentThreadID()` to `GetWindowThreadProcessID(hWnd, NULL)` but it fail, and I don't know why.
Does anything wrong with the code?
p/s: I don't know much about Window Hooks, I learn it from MSDN, here is [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318804)

Comment: This kind of hook requires a DLL that can be injected into the target process(es), 3rd argument of SetWindowsHookEx().  Such a DLL cannot be written in C#, you'll have to learn a language like C or C++ or google the *many* existing web pages about this.  We don't need another, thanks for trying to contribute.

Comment: Thank, my target is "write log about mouse and keyboard", maybe I don't need to use Local hooks, is this possible if I try to get mouse position from Global hook, and filter it by ThreadID or HandleID?

Comment: Yes, you need GetForegroundWindow() to know which window is going to get the mouse/keyboard message.  GetWindowProcessThreadId() tells you which process owns that window.  Whether your user's anti-malware will be happy about such a keylogger is a secondary issue.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for...

But, in your code, instead of setWindowsHookEx(), you've written swtWindowsHookEx().

Maybe if you correct it, you'll get what you're looking for.

cheers and happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

Thank for Hans Passant, I used Global hooks to take all information, then, `GetForegroundWindow()`  to check that with list handles I was had. In this way, I don't need to use DLL, but I still can get Mouse/keyboard message to write key log.